# Jython zxJDBC / Python cx_oracle wrong number or types of arguments when calling to oracle's stored procedure

Tags: python, django, oracle, jython

Trying to make a django test application which will use stored oracle's procedures to insert/get data.

Using jython with zxJDBC but same error applies with python and cx_oracle too.

here is some code snipets:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import connection

class ALEX_TEST_PKG():
    def get_data(self, inparam1):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        ret = cursor.callproc("ALEX_TEST_PKG.test0", inparam1)
        cursor.close
        return ret
```

views.py

```
class TestForm(forms.Form):
    inparam1 = forms.CharField(max_length=500)


def message(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = TestForm()
    if form.is_valid():
        my_util = ALEX_TEST_PKG()
        ret = my_util.get_data(request.POST['inparam1'])
        return HttpResponse(ret)
    return render_to_response('form.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

oracle's procedures:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY ALEX.alex_test_pkg
IS
   PROCEDURE test0 (inparam1 IN integer)
   IS
   BEGIN
      insert into alex_debug(col1) values(inparam1); 
   END test0;
END alex_test_pkg;
/
```

Django error log:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/form/

Django Version: 1.3.1
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'dbtest']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3.1-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "E:\WatchTower\workspace3\erwtwe\erwtwe\dbtest\views.py" in message
  19.         ret = my_util.get_data(request.POST['inparam1'])
File "E:\WatchTower\workspace3\erwtwe\erwtwe\dbtest\models.py" in get_data
  7.         ret = cursor.callproc("ALEX_TEST_PKG.test0", inparam1)

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /form/
Exception Value: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'TEST0'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Any help is appriciated. breaking my head with this for 3 days already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the value from `request.POST`, where it's always a string, but your stored procedure is expecting an integer.

Use `form.cleaned_data['inparam1']` instead - the form will have converted it to the proper type, ie an integer.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters to callproc are expected to be passed in via a list.  You appear to be passing in a string.  My off-hand guess is that Django or cx_Oracle is interpreting that string as a sequence and passing a whole series of 1-character strings to Oracle.

Pass `[inparam1]` instead of just `inparam1` to cursor.callproc.